# Changing widget's highlight color in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I've figured out how to change the background color of PyQt5 widgets using `setStyleSheet()` but I cannot find how to change their highlight color. I am 100% sure this option should be available as in `tkinter`.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton
import sys

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        b1 = QPushButton(parent=self, text='Button')
        color_1 = 'red'
        color_2 = 'blue'
        b1.setStyleSheet('QWidget {background-color: %s}' % color_1)
        #b1.setStyleSheet('QWidget {highlight-color: %s}' % color_2) does not work
        b1.resize(150,50)
        b1.move(100,100)

        self.setGeometry(300,200, 400, 400)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize QPushButton you can use the following style sheet:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        b1 = QPushButton(parent=self, text='Button')
        b1.setGeometry(150,150, 100, 100)


style = '''
QWidget {
    background-color: coral; 
} 

QPushButton {
    background-color: #006325;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;

    min-width:  100px;
    max-width:  100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;

    border-radius: 50px;        
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #ae32a0;
    border-style: solid;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: #328930;
    color: yellow;
}
QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: #80c342;
    color: red;
}    

'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    app.setStyleSheet(style)             # <---

    ex = Example()
    ex.setGeometry(300,200, 400, 400)
    ex.setWindowTitle("QPushButton - style sheet")
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer! I have one question though: Where can I find this kind of style sheet for other widgets as well (in case they are different)? They are not in the docs for PyQt5.